# How can I use Ubuntu and exit out and go back to Windows?

Tags: windows-10

I want to install Ubuntu but I am afraid that I won't be able to go back to Windows. Is there any way I can use Ubuntu and go back to Windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu) and [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/q/133533/)

Comment: Related: [Can I run both Ubuntu and Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473466/can-i-run-both-ubuntu-and-windows)

Comment: Do you mean Dual Booting your system?  Something like https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi ?

Comment: [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119429/asking-if-it-would-be-better-to-install-ubuntu-and-through-virtualbox-handle-win/1119447#1119447) may help you choose between dual booting and selecting a main operating system and installing the other one in a virtual machine (for example using VirtualBox).

Comment: Ubuntu is not an application that you can "exit". It's an Operating System, a peer of Windows. The terms you are using are unclear. If you merely want to try Ubuntu without commitment, then look up how to create a LiveUSB.

Comment: It's off topic here to post it as an answer because it's windows specific way. You can install https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10 then install `xming`https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/ to run a ubuntu application on Windows. Watch this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p53bskgHj1A

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I run both Ubuntu and Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473466/can-i-run-both-ubuntu-and-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want to do in Ubuntu. You could set up a virtual machine in Windows.