# How can I install Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: software-installation, adobe

I am new to Ubuntu. Can anyone tell me how to install Adobe Illustrator?

Comment: Related: [Illustrator alternative](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47347/illustrator-alternative)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. You might be able to run it under wine [depending on the version of illustrator](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=20) you want to run. If not you can always [dual-boot windows or run windows under a VM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473466/can-i-run-both-ubuntu-and-windows)

Comment: What version are you wanting to install?

Answer (score 2):

Illustrator won't run in Linux.

However, Inkscape will.

Inkscape is a vector graphic editor that is quite similar to Illustrator. It can open and edit .ai files from Illustrator. Inkscape saves files as .svg which Illustrator can open, but the layer visibility can be a little wonky sometimes on the Illustrator side. All of the objects will be present in Illustrator so it's manageable.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Illustrator does not support Ubuntu, but you can instead use Inkscape, a free alternative to Adobe Illustrator.
Use the following command in a terminal to install.
`sudo apt install inkscape`

If you prefer GUI, you can also search in the software center for inkscape and install it.